# Reconstruct stack from pointer

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm currently tasked to perform post-mortem debugging using gdb, binary and a core file. Often I encounter the phenomenon of stack trashing where the stack cannot be reconstructed by bt. However, by examining memory I can often recover contiguous parts of the stack area that are still intact, including their frame pointers.

My question now is if I can recover such a frame pointer, is there a gdb command that allows me to reconstruct and print the stack up to this point, including all local variables? Or will the bt command only work up from the current frame pointer?

Regards